# How to add multiple filters to query?

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssms-2012

I'm creating an SSRS report that has a texbox where you can enter a person's ID or name. I'd like to apply this as a filter to the MDX query. Applying the filter to the dataset worked, but the report takes too long to run that way.

Here's the MDX the query designer generated for me:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Employee Count] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { ([Person].[Emplid].[Emplid].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Person].[First Name].[First Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Person].[Last Name].[Last Name].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
```

The logic for the intended filter would be like this:

```
WHERE SearchParameter = [Emplid] OR [First Name] + [Last Name] like SearchParameter
```

I can figure out how fine tune it, I'm just looking for an example of the proper MDX syntax for the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alejandro pointing me in the right direction with the `FILTER` function I was able to come up with a solution. I also had to learn how to use the `INSTR` function to compare values to the parameter.

```
select  {[Measures].[Passed] , [Measures].[Did not pass]} on 0
    , filter(
        {[Person].[Emplid].Children * [Person].[First Name].Children * [Person].[Last Name].Children * [Training List].[Training Display Name].Children},
        instr([Person].[Emplid].currentmember.member_caption, @SearchParameter) > 0 
            or instr([Person].[First Name].currentmember.member_caption + ' ' + [Person].[Last Name].currentmember.member_caption, @SearchParameter) > 0) on 1
from [Model]
```

I hope this will help anyone facing similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to understand how `WHERE` clause in MDX works. `WHERE` clause doesn't filter the Rows axis, it filters the dimension members on the axes that intersects with the members specified in the `WHERE` clause.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ms146047.aspx)

Having said that, you have to specify tuples or set of members in the `WHERE` clause:

Example:

```
WHERE (STRTOMEMBER(@Year))
```

`STRTOMEMBER()` converts a SSRS text parameter (`@Year`) containing `[Date].[Year].&[2016]` value to a valid MDX member. In that case the `WHERE` clause filters the members axes that intersects with the year 2016 in the date dimension.

Also you can use `STRTOSET` to pass multiple members to filter.

```
WHERE StrToSet (@Countries, CONSTRAINED)
```

`@Countries` parameter is a Text SSRS parameter, that contains the `{[Geography].[Geography].[Country].[Germany],[Geography].[Geography].[Country].[Canada]}` members.

In that case the `WHERE` clause will filter the members specified in the SELECT clause that intersects with the countries Canada and Germany.

UPDATE: Based on OP feed.

This should work.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Employee Count] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
{
  ( StrToMember ( '[Person].[Emplid].&[123]' ) * [Person].[First Name].[First Name].AllMembers * [Person].[Last Name].[Last Name].AllMembers )
} Dimension Properties MEMBER_CAPTION,
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM [Model]
```

Note I am not using the `WHERE` clause but specifying the member in the rows Axis.

**UPDATE:** I think the `WHERE` clause is not suited for your requeriment, it seems you need to use FILTER functions to select some members based on some conditions.

As I said previously, `WHERE` clause filters the members in your axes that intersects with the given members. `Filter` function can be used to filter members that meet the the given criteria.

*[FILTER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/ms146037.aspx)*

> Returns the set that results from filtering a specified set based on a
>   search condition.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{
     [Measures].[Score %]
    ,[Measures].[Month Key]
} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
{
    ([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307])
    * 
    FILTER
    (
        [Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
        [Measures].[Score %] <> null
        AND 
        [Measures].[Score %] <> 0
    )
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Note in the above MDX query, there is a crossjoin between months `201301` to `201307` and some members that meet the criteria specified in the filter function. The criteria in this case is that the `Score %` of the members cannot be null `AND` cannot be zero.

It should produce something like this:

```
MonthName  Customer Full Name  Score %  Month Key

 201301       Customer1          5%       1000
 201301       Customer2          3%       1000
 201304       Customer1          8%       3500
 201306       Customer1         11%       2200
 201307       Customer2         13%       3400
```

Note Months 201302, 201303 and 201305 are not present in the result because the customers in those months don't meet the filter criteria.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: When I try to refer to the EMPLID in the WHERE clause I get this error" `The Emplid hierarchy already appears in the Axis1 axis.`

Comment: Share the MDX, I think you are trying to select Emplid on rows and filter it in the slicer where clause.

Comment: `SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Employee Count] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { ([Person].[Emplid].[Emplid].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Person].[First Name].[First Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Person].[Last Name].[Last Name].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [Model]
WHERE STRTOMEMBER('[Person].[Emplid].&[123]')`

Comment: You cannot have the same dimension in multiple axes, so the Person dimension can only appear once in (rows, columns, or where clause) since where clause is a slicer (like another axis). I'll try to fix your query in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. We're half way there. How do you work an `OR` statement into that?